# Oracle SQL replace some string in a string FAST

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace, query-optimization

I have a really simple problem:
Replace XX_FistName LastName (maybe dr. or phd anything trash) to firstname lastname

now i am using regexp replace:

```
trim(regexp_replace(lower(vhc.name),'xx_|dr|\.|\,|phd|jr','')
```

but this is really really slow...
can you give me some hint how can i replace this something faster? I have too much data to compare and do other functions on these data and it takes hours.

Comment: If you are comparing the expression, you need a function-based index. If you can tell us what exactly is the query and some sample data, someone can provide you a specific answer.

Comment: @Csanesz _regexp_ have the reputation of being slow. Mostly because they require to be somehow compiled before processing. But once done, they are not _that slow_ at all (esp. without loops and lookahead). Could you show your actual query? How many rows do you have? Any index on the relevant rows?

Answer (score 1):

A reduced one.

```
trim(regexp_replace(lower(vhc.name),'xx_|[dj]r|[.,]|phd','')
```

Comment: thx but i actually want to drop this regexp replace and something else if its exists.

Comment: @Csanesz the slowness could be with your query. `regexp_replace` is bit CPU intensive but not that slow. Can you share your query

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but might help someone landing here just like me.

```
replace(table1.column_here, 'string_to_be_replaced', 'to_replace_with')
```